# Minimum number of registers for mutual exclusion

Tags: distributed-systems, parallel-computing, mutual-exclusion

I was reading distributed algorithms (by Nancy lynch) and there is a part that I would kindly like to get a simpler explanation for.

I know the book mentioned no algorithm can solve mutual exclusion between n processes with less than n variables. But I fail to fully understand the proof, can someone please give a slightly simpler explanation?

For example, for the sake of contradiction, the book gave the example of 2 process and 1 shared variable and showed that it violates mutual exclusion, but I fail to understand why can't we simply use 1 (atomic) lock variable with some atomic testAndSet?

```
lock: variable initialized at 0 (0=>unlocked, access available)
//code for proc i:
while testAndSet(lock)==0{  //test and as soon as look=0, set it to 1 and enter critical section
 //busy wait}

// do critical stuff here and release lock when done
lock =0
```

Since the testandSet is considered atomic, so I see no reason it should not work, if both processes try to obtain it at the same time, only one of them will get the lock before the other, and when the other does the test, it will know someone set the lock to 1 earlier.

Can someone please simplify the proof to tell me what is wrong with the example I gave?

Thanks